# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable in Jarvis A.I

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

I am very sorry for asking a noob question because I am a very new guy to python.

My program is an A.I. like Jarvis.

My problem is that when I run my program it gives me an error:

**`TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`**

The full error is:

```
**C:\Users\jobro\anaconda3\envs\Jarvis\pythonw.exe C:/Users/jobro/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/main.py
Please Speak...

    Voice Input :  None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/jobro/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/main.py", line 61, in <module>
        if validate_input(voice_input, greeting_cmd):
      File "C:/Users/jobro/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/main.py", line 21, in validate_input
        if cmd in input:
    TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
    
    Process finished with exit code 1**
```

Here is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
import os
import platform
import speech_recognition as sr

speech = sr.Recognizer()

# Getting OS name
os_name = platform.platform()

# Commands
launch_cmd = ['open', 'launch', 'run']
greeting_cmd = ['hello jarvis', 'hi jarvis', 'wakeup jarvis']

launch_dict = {'project': 'C:\\Users\\jobro\\PycharmProjects', 'projects': 
               'C:\\Users\\jobro\\PycharmProjects',
               'youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/'}


def validate_input(input, commands):
    for cmd in commands:
        if cmd in input:
            return True


def get_launch_value(voice_input):
    for key, value in launch_dict.items():
        if key in voice_input:
            return value


try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', 
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech\\Voices\\Tokens\\TTS_MS_EN-US_DAVID_11.0')
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)


def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def read_voice_cmd():
    print('Please Speak...')
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = speech.listen(source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=5)
    try:
        return speech.recognize_google(audio_data=audio).lower()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


while True:
    voice_input = read_voice_cmd()
    print('Voice Input : ', voice_input)
    if validate_input(voice_input, greeting_cmd):
        speak('Hello Sir, How may I help you?')
        continue
    elif validate_input(voice_input, launch_cmd):
        path = get_launch_value(voice_input)
        if os_name == 'Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0':
            cmd = 'start '
        else:
            cmd = 'explorer '
        if os_name == 'Darwin':
            cmd = 'start'
        cmd = cmd + path

        os.system(cmd)

    else:
        speak('Command not found.')
        continue
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop you start with

```
while True:
    voice_input = read_voice_cmd()
    print('Voice Input : ', voice_input)
```

This is printing

```
Voice Input :  None
```

So you're not detecting any voice input. Then you pass this value of `None` to the `validate_input` function, and try to check if it contains certain commands using `if cmd in input:`

Since `a in b` requires `b` to be a sequence, and `None` is not an iterable, this throws an error. Concentrate on fixing the voice input part, so that you actually detect some speech, and the print statement does not return `Voice input : None`.